# iOS или Android?

Tags: android, ios

Не подскажите, что сейчас изучать перспективнее: iOS или Android? С точки зрения востребованности у работодателей.

Comment: Изучают не iOS, изучают язык и библиотеки, Objective-C. Также что бы кодить под iOS нужна система с MacOS, iMac, MacMini или MacBook какой нибудь.

Comment: Objective-C + cocoa-touch я изучил (на уровне любителя), зарегистрировался на их сайте, чтобы запускать свои приложения на айпаде. Понятно, что для этого нужен Mac ;) Но это никак не влияет на перспективность iOS.

Comment: Влияет, затраты. И на сколько я помню там и айфон, не только iPad прилы. Ну скажу еслиб у меня шас были финансы на мак ось я бы позанимался, в айфон разработке есть свои преспективы которые хотелось бы изучить(многие мне уже известны, но нужна практика), в андроиде свои, уже мне известные.

Comment: @AndroidDev есть ведь хакинтош. Никаких затрат вообще не требует.

Comment: Купить железку с маком не затраты?

Comment: Mac прекрассно работает в VirtualBox

Comment: @AndroidDev либо вы меня не поняли, либо я вас

Comment: Я про то что XCode поставить только на маки можно.

Comment: Отнюдь. Xcode работает в Mac OS X. А она, в свою очередь, успешно работает на PC-шном железе.

Comment: Мне больше по душе AppCode. XCode - очень неудобная IDE, она даже не сортирует файлы с исходниками в дереве проекта.

Comment: @Angry Bird Выбор IDE -  это личное дело каждого разработчика. Кому-то нравится одно, кому-то другое. Насчет AppCode - да, это, собственно, единственная альтернатива Xcode'у на сегодняшний момент. Однако он еще далек от финальной версии - поэтому наблюдается некоторая нестабильность в работе.
Про невозможность сортировки в Xcode - там сам принцип работы другой. Файлы\каталоги разбиваются именно на логические группы. Поэтому сортировка "не нужна".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

И так вот подробный ответ с моими рассуждениями:

iOS:

- Основной язык - Objective-C
- Магазин приложений - AppStore
- В магазине больше платных приложений чем бесплатных, пользователи охотно покупают приложения по приемлимой цене в 1-2$
- Возможность разместить в приложении рекламу с большим охватом и прибылью, работать сразу с рекламными 10-12 компаниями и показывать всех их объявления (Обновление раз в 30 секунд, показ следующего). Предоставляет такой сервис как Mobclix. В данной сфере лично эффективность рекламы не тестировал
- Относительно дешевая и выгодная реклама приложений (Относительно эффективности не знаю)
- Нет проблем совместимости, пишется под один девайс, с одним размером экрана и набором функций
- При размещении приложений низкий % отказа пользователей, нет проблем совместимости, многие юзеры не качают приложение что бы 10 минут с ним поиграться.

Android:

- Основный язык - Java
- Магазин приложений - AndroidMarket
- Пользователи не особо активно покупают платные версии приложений, из за открытости платформы предпочитают бесплатные версии.
- Возможность разместить в приложении рекламу с огромным охватом и
     прибылью, работать сразу с рекламными 8-9 компаниями(Включая OpenAllocation - AbMob, AdWords) и показывать всех их объявления (Обновление раз в 30 секунд, показ следующего). Предоставляет такой как сервис Mobclix.
- Если рекламодатель платит за показы или установки приложения иногда получается очень прибыльным занятием.
- Достаточно не дешевая реклама своего приложения (0.03-0.04$ за клик по баннеру,если платить за инсталлы то 0.25-1$ за установку)
- Проблемы совместимости, разные размеры экранов, разные версии системы, встречал даже такое что один функционал работающий на моем девайсе не работает на некоторых других моделях
- При размещении приложений и скачиванием их юзерами большой процент отказов, обычно даже бывает доходит до 40-50% (Следствием того является пункт выше + многие юзеры качают приложение "поразвлекаться")

Comment: Привел пункты которые волнуют меня как разработчика.

Comment: >Нет проблем совместимости, пишется под один девайс, с одним размером экрана и набором
>функций
Позвольте поправить:
1) разные версии ОС на разных девайсах, разные фичи опять же.
2) разрешение экрана все же разное (Retina и простое) - так что дизайн надо будет подстраивать в любом случае (если нужен больший охват девайсов, конечно).
3) производительность того же iPhone 4 и 2G - небо-земля. Есть много приложений которые летают на первом и вообще никак не работают на втором (это опять же вопрос про охват).

Comment: Но это не 320 разных устройств на базе Android, так что в данном случае фрагментацией iPhone можно пренебречь.

Comment: Ну как пренебречь... Она, конечно, меньше в разы, но все же учитывать это стоит по-любому.

Comment: Вообще никаких проблем с этим нет, дизайнеру просто надо рисовать графику под ретину и складывать в папку с именем image@2x, а с помощью доп. утилит, в один клик вся графика уменьшается в 2 раза и подгоняется под обычный экран. С точки зрения кода, ничего вообще не меняется.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, а сами чего вы хотите? Сейчас более востребован iOS. Но андроид очень быстро набирает обороты так, что вскоре андроид станет более преспективной платформой.

Answer (score 1):

Не стоит зацикливаться на одной платформе. Существуют проссплатформенные SDK для мобильных устройств, например, AirPlaySDK или Titanium. Они позволяют написать мобильное приложение один раз и скомпилировать его практически под все мобильные платформы.

Answer (score 0):

Под iOS можно не только на Objective-C писать, можно и на C# в Monotouch. Но без мака никуда... (говорят (c), что можно попытаться установить хакинтош ).
На мой взгляд, оба эти направления перспективны. Плюс Андроида в том, что для него можно разрабатывать под виндой, то есть можно работать фрилансером или обучаться самостоятельно без ощутимых финансовых вложений.

Comment: Ну да, в основе используеться обджектив-с, я также могу сказать что под андроид тоже можно писать не на яве а на с++(вспоминаем про NDK) в маке основной проблемой и является покупка самой железки с красивым надкусанным яблоком)

Comment: Тут тоже смотря с какой стороны посмотреть, для разработки под Android нужно покупать девайс, а лучше 3 с разными экранами.
А под iOS можнос покойно кодить и тестить в эмуляторе даже игры.

Answer (score 0):

iOS  но есть минус : надо иметь для 100% разработки Mac железо :) Вот я обладатель macbook о Xcode (objective-c) никогда не увлекался, только php, mysql & c++

Comment: Вы наверно 4ый кто уже написал про этот минус)

Answer (score 0):

Лучше iOs так как там приложения активней покупают... А если перейдешь на мак, то про писи забудешь поверь мне)

Answer (score -1):

Да, iOS сейчас изучать перспективнее. Не думаю, что вскоре что-то изменится...